# Solving $f''(x) = -f(x)$ without using Euler's formula

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, complex-numbers

As part of a proof to Euler's formula, I got to the differential equation       $f(x) = -f''(x).$
I already know that the solution to this equation is: $f(x) = c_1 \sin(x) + c_2 \cos(x),$ but beside the fact that both $\sin$ and $\cos$ satisfy this equation, how can I prove this lemma? And preferably without using Euler's formula, so that this could be a valid proof.

Comment: Multiply with $f‘(x)$ and integrate

Comment: Use a power series method.

Comment: You have written two linearly independent solutions to a second order linear homogeneous ordinary differential equation.  What more is there to prove?

Comment: Use that this is a homogeneous linear equation of order 2

Comment: It depends on your definition of sine and cosine functions. Because some people even those functions as solutions to this differential equation (with different initial conditions).

Comment: Define them as such that the vector <$cos(t)$, $sin(t$)> traces out a unit circle starting at <$1,0$> when $t \in$ [0, 2$\pi$]

Answer (score 1):

You can solve that equation using this:
$$\frac {f''}{f}=\left (\frac {f'}{f}\right )'+\left (\frac {f'}{f} \right )^2$$
Substitute $u=\frac {f'}{f}$
$$u'+u^2=-1$$
This is separable.

Answer (score 0):

Say you've computed $f$ numerically (using, say, Euler's method). That is, you don't know a formula for $f$, but you know some values of $f$ to some decimal places. If you graph $f$ you'll see a wave, but let's say you don't recognize that graph.

One thing we can do is plot the *configuration space*. This will be $\vec r(t)=(f(t),f'(t))$, a point on the plane depending on $t$ (as well as the initial conditions of $f$). If you do this, one thing will surprise you: no matter the initial conditions of $f$, the point $\vec r(t)=(f(t),f'(t))$ appears to move in circles around the origin! Furthermore, the angular velocity seems to always be 1 (equivalently, the velocity equals the radius).

So, inspired by your empirical findings, you make three conjectures: one, that the point is a constant radius away from the origin (aka $\|\vec r(t)\|=C$), and two, that the point is moving at a constant velocity (aka $\|\vec r'(t)\|=C$), and third, the radius and the velocity are equal (aka $\|\vec r\|=\|\vec r'\|$).

To prove the first one, we see that we want to prove:
\begin{align}
\|r(t)\|&=C\\
\sqrt{(f)^2+(f')^2}&=C\\
(f)^2+(f')^2&=C^2\\
\left((f)^2+(f')^2\right)'&=0
\end{align}
Now, we prove this, using $f''=-f$:
\begin{align}
\left((f)^2+(f')^2\right)'&=2ff'+2f'f''\\
&=2ff'+2f'(-f)\\
&=2ff'-2ff'\\
&=0
\end{align}
and the first conjecture is proved. The next two are similar: I leave them as exercises to you.

Now we know that $(f(t),f'(t))$ travels around a circle with constant angular velocity 1, and a little trigonometry tells you that the equation for that is $(R\cos(t+\varphi),R\sin(t+\varphi))$ where $R$ is the radius of the circle and $\varphi$ is the offset (it tells you where on the circle you start). Thus:
$$f(t)=R\cos(t+\varphi)$$
And we didn't even need to know what the derivative of cosine is! Some trigonometry will show that this is equivalent to your solution.

---

Note that, while our solution and proof is something that could be done on pencil and paper, our *conjectures* that we made at the start required us to have computed $f$ for some values! So it often goes: to make real progress, sometimes you have to get your hands dirty.

In general, this is how it goes in research math (and, once upon a time, this was research math): you have a problem, you have no idea how to solve it, you do lots of calculating, you spot a pattern, and that lets you get a foothold into solving the problem. (And then you hide all the ugly computations by the time you write a paper, so that it looks like you knew what you were doing all along.)

Comment: (I suppose technically this leaves open the question of $\vec r(t)$ traveling clockwise or counterclockwise. In fact it always travels counterclockwise, which you can see by looking at what happens when it crosses the $y$-axis.)

Comment: The philosophy here is [iterated distillation and amplification](https://youtu.be/v9M2Ho9I9Qo). Computation is slow, but it "amplifies" our powers because it lets us see new patterns. We then "distill" those patterns into new tools in our toolbox. Now we can iterate the process again, using those new tools in our computations. This is why mathematics has gotten so far.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for the comments and answers. I wanted to share with you a solution I found out for this problem.
After treating the system like a [harmonic oscillator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_oscillator) (it satisfies this equation when $\frac{k}{m} = \frac{1}{sec^2} $), I realized there is general formula which works for any ordinary differential equation.
let $y$ be a function of $x$, then: $$\int_{y_0}^{y(x)} y'' dy =
  \left.\frac{y'^2}{2}\right\vert_{y'_0}^{y'(x)}$$ which is basically just the [work energy theorem](https://www.khanacademy.org/science/ap-physics-1/ap-work-and-energy/work-energy-theorem-ap/a/work-energy-theorem-ap1) after division by the mass (I will prove this result at the end of this answer).
Using this formula and setting $y'' = -y$ we get:
$$\int_{y_0}^{y(x)} -y dy = \left.\frac{y'^2}{2}\right\vert_{y'_0}^{y'(x)}$$
$$\left.\frac{-y^2}{2}\right\vert_{y_0}^{y(x)} = \left.\frac{y'^2}{2}\right\vert_{y'_0}^{y'(x)}$$
$$y_0^2-y(x)^2 = y'(x)^2 - y_0'^2$$
which is a (relatively) simple separable first order differential equation.

proof of the formula:

1. Evaluate the integral $$\int_{y_0}^{y(x)} y'' dy$$
2. Rewrite $y''$ as $\frac{dy'}{dx}$
3. Use step two to change $y''dy$ to $\frac{dy'}{dx}dy$, then to $dy'\frac{dy}{dx}$
4. Notice that $\frac{dy}{dx} = y'$ so $dy'\frac{dy}{dx} = y'dy' = \frac{(\frac{dy}{dx})^2}{2} + C$
   And so $$\int_{y_0}^{y(x)} y'' dy =
     \left.\frac{y'^2}{2}\right\vert_{y'_0}^{y'(x)}$$
   (The change of the limits of integration from $y(x)$ and $y_0$ on the left to $y'(x)$ and $y'_0$ on the right, comes from the fact that we ended up integrating by $dy'$, not by $dy$, and so the limits must change to the limits of $y'$.)